Given a singular matrix $B$ and a result $C=A\times B$, find matrix $A$ over finite fields.
The problem is a conituation of this problem, but over finite fields.
In the context of a finite integer field, particularly when all entries in matrices $A, B$, and $C$ are drawn from a finite integer field, the SVD may not yield results, as SVD works well for matrices with real or complex number entries. Consequently, the approach outlined in the solution to this problem would also be ineffective.
My current question is as follows.

$C=A\times B$, where $B\in\mathbb{F}_q^{n\times n}$ is a singular square matrix, $Rank(B)=n/2$, $A\in \mathbb{F}_q^{n\times n}$ is a full rank matrix, $q$ is a prime.
Given $C$ and $B$, how to find $A'\in \mathbb{F}_q^{n\times n}$, such that $A'\times B=C$?
Is there an "infinite" number of solutions $A'$ meeting $A'\times B=C$?


An example over $\mathbb{F}_q$, $q=65537$.
The singular matrix $B=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}45486&33969&47434&1129\\50585&30352&54018&33044\\18346&16233&7013&13403\\12177&36523&16428&26582\end{array}\right)$.
The result $\left.C=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}9605&8658&35595&34119\\59342&35066&46074&35682\\57149&58797&40560&62867\\6125&9457&30785&58689\end{array}\right.\right)$.

Is there any efficient method to recover the correct matrix $A$? or partial entries in $A$?

The matrix $\left.A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}26903&56799&35632&41350\\49093&15412&25540&13964\\14708&23535&3827&63911\\56190&32614&6340&41196\end{array}\right.\right)$


The link in your first sentence is broken.  Try using Rank Normal Form.

@user8675309 Thank you, I have fixed the link. And could you give me more information about how to generate such $A'$ making $A'\times B = C$?
